# How to change active application in progress?

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

In Progress 11.3.2 (Developer Studio 3.7 - Eclipse 3.8.2), not using dot net at all:

How do you switch the focus to another window/application/w file?

In windows 7/8 the order of what window that is focused acts a bit different than before and does not always show the window you want to have over all the other apps.

If you have 3 windows open, and close the 3rd one and want to focus on the second one that was minimized, the first one get focus instead.

You set it to normal with WINDOW-STATE = WINDOW-NORMAL. But how to focus on it too?

Answer (score 1):

If you run the secondary windows persistent you can do something like this:

In calling window:

```
/* In definitions */
DEFINE VARIABLE ghSecondWindow AS HANDLE      NO-UNDO.

/* In a trigger */
RUN secondWindow.w PERSISTENT SET ghSecondWindow.

/* Whenever you want to shift focus */
RUN setFocus IN ghSecondWindow.
```

In "SecondWindow":

```
PROCEDURE setFocus:
  /* Replace FILL-IN-1 with any widget that can gain focus */
  APPLY "ENTRY" TO FILL-IN-1 IN FRAME {&FRAME-NAME}. 
END PROCEDURE.
```

If however you are not running persistent windows you can still achieve this by walking the widget trees, first of the current window and then of the second window (once you've localized it).

Quick and ugly code to put in the calling window wherever you want the focus to shift. This might not suit your needs exactly so it might require some rewriting. Also error checking is pretty much not here and dealing with possible eternal loops without error checking is not really best practice:

```
DEFINE VARIABLE hWin    AS HANDLE      NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE hWidget AS HANDLE      NO-UNDO.

/* Get the first child (widget) of the session */
ASSIGN 
    hWin  = SESSION:FIRST-CHILD.

/* Loop through all widgets in the session */
loop:
DO WHILE VALID-HANDLE(hWin):

    /* We've identified the correct Window! */
    IF hWin:TYPE = "WINDOW" AND hWin:TITLE = "Secondary Window" THEN DO:

        /* ** Very Ugly** this could use better error checking etc! */
        /* Get the second field-group of the window */
        /* This will depend on your layout with different frames etc */
        /* What we really have is WINDOW:DEFAULT-FRAME:FIELD-GROUP:FIELD-GROUP */
        /* Field groups are really only present in the widget tree - they lack visual */
        /* representation */
        /* Read about field-groups in the online help! */
        ASSIGN 
            hWidget = hWin:FIRST-CHILD:FIRST-CHILD:FIRST-CHILD.

        /* Loop through all widgets of the field-group */
        DO WHILE VALID-HANDLE(hWidget).

            /* We've found the correct fill-in, give it focus */
            IF hWidget:TYPE = "FILL-IN" AND hWidget:LABEL = "Fill 1" THEN DO:
                APPLY "ENTRY" TO hWidget.
                LEAVE loop.
            END.

            /* Next window of the correct window */
            hWidget = hWidget:NEXT-SIBLING.

        END.
    END.
    /* Next widget of the session */
    hWin = hWin:NEXT-SIBLING.
END.
```

You could also do the "widget tree walk" recursively if you feel like it!